# How to install the slime into emacs under Windows7

Tags: emacs, lisp, slime

**How to install the slime into emacs under Win7?**

I download a compact package with '.tgz'. But it seems for linux. But there is really not one thing for windows(win 32 OS).

I unfold this package and I find there are lots of documents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually [the same as for other operating systems](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Getting-started.html#Getting-started), as far as I can tell. (At least, it always worked for me under FreeBSD/ArchLinux/Win7.) First, you unpack to a location you like, then add something like this to your .emacs (assuming you unpacked somewhere under your user directory):

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/my/path/to/slime/")
;; (add-to-list 'load-path "~/my/path/to/slime/contrib/") ; for optional features

(slime-setup
;; '(slime-fancy slime-asdf slime-references              ; optional features
;;   slime-indentation slime-xref-browser)
)

(setq slime-lisp-implementations
      '((ccl ("~/path/to/ccl/wx86cl"))
        (clisp ("~/path/to/clisp-2.49/clisp" "-modern"))) ; giving a command arg
      slime-default-lisp 'ccl)
```

Restart Emacs or type `C-x C-e` behind each of these toplevel forms. Then, type `M-x slime RET` (or `C-u M-x slime RET` if you want to choose between the implementations in `slime-lisp-implementations`, otherwise `slime-lisp-default` will be used) and it should just work (it does for me). The setting of `slime-lisp-implementations` is optional – you can also give the path to your lisp implementation executable by hand when starting Slime.

Assuming you want to use Slime with CL, since there is no Clojure tag. If you want to use it with Clojure, things are unfortunately a little different and both versions don't play very nicely together. The recommended way for use with Clojure, last time I checked, would be installation using the package system of Emacs 24 or, if you're using an older version, ELPA (which is essentially the same).

Comment: Tank you very much. And what is 'ccl'? Do I need to download it?

Comment: In the example configuration above, the symbols `ccl` and `clisp` are names of Common Lisp implementations, the programs the path points to. They are needed in order to compile and run Lisp code. `ccl` for Clozure Common Lisp (http://ccl.clozure.com/), `clisp` for CLISP (http://www.clisp.org/). Slime itself is just an Emacs-based development environment, not a Lisp implementation. So, yes, you'll need to download at least one Lisp implementation and either give the path to the executable when starting slime, or preconfigure them in `slime-lisp-implementations` as above.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

- Get a Slime copy from https://github.com/slime/slime, either by `git clone` or by downloading the zip. Unzip and save it in `D:/myuser/slime-2.13`, for example
- Download and install [CLISP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clisp/)
- Add this to the `.emacs` file, usually located in `C:/users/myuser/AppData/Roaming`:

  ```
  ; This is the path where you've saved Slime in the first step
  (add-to-list 'load-path "D:/myuser/slime-2.13/")
  (require 'slime-autoloads)
  ; This is the path where CLISP was installed. 
  ; Use Progra~1 for "Program Files" and Progra~2 for "Program Files (x86)"
  (setq inferior-lisp-program "/C/Progra~2/clisp-2.49/clisp.exe")
  ```